# TYPO3 CMS Backend; Login Type

Tags: php, typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I have a service running in one of my extensions which talks to an outside API which is login protected (loginname + loginpassword is needed) and therefore I must store the login information somewhere.

In the developing process I had this information stored in the TS config of my extension.

But now I'm thinking; theres no easy way to have my customer change the login information eg. when they're forced to reset the API logins.
And also: I have to know the login information, too. And its stored in plain-text.

Now I'm thinking; whats the best / easiest way to store the login information easily available to the customer? Would it be a flexform which is simply stored in the database then somewhere (encrypted?) or is it something else?
Would it be in the constans (but only an admin has access to these information, ...?)

Anyone has an idea what to do?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use the extension 
[DCE](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/dce)

Which it I can simply create new content elements (such as Elements which only covers the Login Information etc.) and give access to those to the editor.

Answer (score 0):

you can set it in TS setup. It is easy to change for the customer if he has enough access rights

as for me I would store it in DB, I would create a simple model for that. User could access it via List tool and BE and I would encrypt it. Model would allow you to get easy access to data from DB and in getters and setters you could manage the encrypt/decrypt

Comment: I had it set up in TS setup (hardcoded). The customer couldnt access / interpret any of the TS setup and therefore I looked for an easier solution.

Comment: TS in not safe solution for this kind of things. If you have some kind of password you always should keep it saved as encrypted string

Comment: Yes, thats why I was looking for an alternative solution rather than keeping those kind of things in plain text somewhere on the filesystem. :)